# Class name not found in main method - python

Tags: python, program-entry-point

So my code is:

```
class myClass:

    @staticmethod
    def func():
        print('foo')

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        myClass.func()
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myClass.py", line 1, in <module>
    class myClass:
  File "myClass.py", line 8, in myClass
    myClass.func()
NameError: name 'myClass' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The `if __name__` .. *shouldn't* be *inside* the class definition (ie. it's indented too much, and should be in the "main" file whatever that is). Also, make sure the posted code is the actual code / issue .. it changed a good bit from the first edits.

Comment: It could be an indentation method. Remove indentation in the block starting with `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: python != java. `main` is not a method here, indeed, there are no functions defined as `main`. Regardless, there is nothing special about a `main` function in python.

Comment: Note, the text in the [main] tag: "In many programming languages, the main function, subroutine, or method marks the entry point of the program. It is generally the first-programmer-written function run when a program starts." Python is not one of those languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an indentation issue.

```
class myClass:

    @staticmethod
    def func():
        print('foo')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myClass.func()
```

The above will work fine in a Python interpreter. Currently, in your code, it is trying to run `myClass.func()` inside the `if` block INSIDE the `class` definition, i.e. when it is trying to create `myClass`, it is trying to run `myClass.func()` and it is failing with the error mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
class myClass:

    @staticmethod
    def func():
       print('foo')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myClass.func()
```